# Reading specific element from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I feel this is really stupid but can't seem to figure it out.

I have a Combobox that populates from an XML file and works great.
Now I want to display a specific element (Description) when an item is selected, but the string always wants to return null.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Barbarian>
  <Special id="Lesser Ancestor Totem">
    <SpecialName>Lesser Ancestor Totem</SpecialName>
    <Description>Gain a +2 Insight Bonus to a skill (that you can use while raging) while raging</Description>
  </Special>
</Barbarian>
```

Code to get the description and put into a RichTextBox:

```
 public void LoadFeatDescription()
        {
            string Class = CharClassSelector.Text;
            string Feat = FeatPicker.Text;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load($"\\Xml\\Classes\\{Class}.xml");

            string description = doc.XPathSelectElement($"//Special[@id='{Feat}']/Description").Value;
            //the string description wants to stay null despite my efforts
            DescriptionBox.Text = description;
                 
        }
```

The idea is that this will load a specific file and get the description element based on the id.
Am I missing something stupid?

Thanks!

Edit: added in the entire XML contents

Comment: Did you show the entire xml or only part of it? Do you have any namespaces in xml?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I did leave out the root.
```
<Barbarian>
    <Special id="Lesser Ancestor Totem">
      <SpecialName>Lesser Ancestor Totem</SpecialName>
      <Description>Gain a +2 Insight Bonus to a skill (that you can use while raging) while raging</Description>
    </Special>
</Barbarian>
```
But even putting that in the XpathSelectElement yields a null value.

Comment: Use Following : string description = (string)doc.Descendants("Description").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng That does get the description, but only for the first one. When I try to add any more, it will only ever show the first one. I need to be able to get the description of the item based on the id.

Comment: Change : string[] description = doc.Descendants("Description").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Changed `string description = doc.XPathSelectElement($"//Special[@id='{Feat}']/Description").Value;`
to
`string description = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"//Special[@id='{Feat}']/Description").Value;`

I knew it was something stupid...